# Directly creating a pyodbc connection works but using sql.alchemyurl does not work

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyodbc, alembic

This works fully as expected.

```
import pyodbc

connection = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=test;UID=SA;PWD=<YourStrong@Passw0rd>", autocommit=True)
```

Why is this and what is going on?

However, when I try to connect with this connection string (I'm trying to setup Alembic) it does not work:

```
sqlalchemy.url = mssql+pyodbc://SA:<YourStrong@Passw0rd>@localhost/test?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server
```

Comment: Does your password really have an `@` in it?

Comment: Can we assume from your [subsequent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75174220/2144390) that you were able to get Alembic to connect to your database?

Comment: Hi @GordThompson, I had missed your answer. But your suggestion was correct, I figured it out after a while and forgot to delete/answer this question. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it :). Do you know the answer to the my subsequent question perhaps? :P